# Guides on Python for shared-memory Parallel Programming

Tags: parallel-computing, python

I have experience in coding OpenMP for Shared Memory machines (in both C and FORTRAN) to carry out simple tasks like matrix addition, multiplication etc. (Just to see how it competes with LAPACK). I know OpenMP enough to carry out simple tasks without the need to look at documentation.

Recently, I shifted to Python for my projects and I don't have any experience with Python beyond the absolute basics.

I have 2 questions:

- Is there a good guide (online PDF) for describing shared memory parallel computing for Python?
- What is the best way of achieving it? I have seen a bit of `ctypes` and I'm not sure if that's the best way.
  (By best I mean one which has a good tradeoff between programmer time and system time. It shouldn't be too tedious to code neither should the execution be slow)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is my first post and I hope I have not completely misunderstood the use of SE - if so I apologize in advance]

I agree with "bgschaid" that the question is very difficult to answer based on the information provided.  It makes a huge difference if you want low-level routines to exploit a multi-core architecture or if you need to exploit parallelism for embarrassingly parallel problems - or something in-between. An overview of different parallel computing possibilities in Python can be found [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).

In the former case I for sure recommend to use tools such as **NumPy** / **SciPy** which at least in the MKL compiled version from Enthought supports multi-core architectures. Here you can control the number of cores to use via the environment variable "MKL_NUM_THREADS".  This relies on highly optimized libraries that we can hardly expect to beat performance wise.  I believe it is generally advised to use these high quality and highly optimized libraries whenever possible.

If you wish to exploit parallelism at a coarse level, the Python standard tool **multiprocessing** is easy to use - and it also supports shared data objects.  There are different tools to use as part of the **multiprocessing** package.  I have used **map_async** (SIMD like) and **apply_async** (MIMD like) for several problems with good results.  The **multiprocessing** package is quite easy to use and being a standard part of Python means that you can expect other potential users of your code to easily be able to use it.  **multiprocessing** also links to NumPy data objects directly.  When using **multiprocessing** I would recommend you to set the environment variable "MKL_NUM_THREADS" to 1 such that **NumPy** is only allowed one core for each process/worker - otherwise you could end up in a resource contention between NumPy parallel and **multiprocessing** which leads to a performance degradation.  **multiprocessing** works fine for a multi-CPU/multi-core architecture under the same operating system.  I have used **multiprocessing** on a shared memory computer with 4 x Xeon E7-4850 CPUs (each 10 cores) and 512 GB memory and it worked extremely well.  Shared arrays can be handled by **multiprocessing.Array** or **sharedctypes**.  You can find the Python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/download.html) - check the **library.pdf** file.  I have some slides explaining some of the basic parts of this - PM me if you want those.

If you have a cluster configuration with distributed memory I believe **mpi4py** is likely the preferred tool.  I have not used this myself but I know that it is being used a lot in Python parallel programming.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the level you're trying to program parallel. For instance for matrix/vector stuff the first stop with python would be NumPy/SciPy (they provide an interface to numeric libraries which gives you the full speed of the libraries with the convenience of Python) and from [what they write about parallelism](http://www.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming) it seems that if the libraries are compiled for parallel use then the programs take advantage of multicores for certain operations. (seems like this article is a bit older, os things might have improved in the meantime. Also there are links to other means of parallel programming.

And of course there is [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/index.html) to directly program MPI (included in the above article)

My bottom line is: if your main interest is vector/matrix-operations and parallelism is something you "only" need to do it fast then you should have a look at the NumPy/SciPy-ecosystem and only if you don't find the stuff there that you need should you consinder writing your own libraries